# Session ID and variables in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a login page where once a user is logged in successfully it echos a link to their personal page.  When that page loads I want it to check if the user has access to it so someone doesn't try to just type in www.mywebsite.com/bob.php in the url.  I tried to use a cookie to send the user info but I realized you can't use cookies after html has been written to the page.  Does anyone know an efficient way to do this that is also fairly simple? Thanks

Comment: Why don’t you store that information in the session?

Comment: At the top of the profile page check the session variable against the user profile's info. e.g. `<?php if ($_SESSION['logginInUserID'] == $profileUserID){ /* success */ }else{ header('Location: http://mysite.com/'); } ?>`

Comment: Why not have the "personal page" generated dynamically, rather than having a unique file for each user?

Comment: @jnpcl: well, you can have both. A dynamically generated page with a nice URL, very easy using mod_rewrite :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the user logs in, assign his id to a session variable:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["userid"] = $userid;
?>
```

On the protected page, check if the user has a $_SESSION["userid"] variable set:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
   //show page
}else{
  echo "No rights";
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow someone to access all the personal pages once they are logged in?

Comment: It would be wise to check `if ($_SESSION['userid'] == $userid) { /* show page */ }` as well ;)

Comment: Oh, yes. I assumed the person meant it was something like a profile page, that only logged in users could see of eachother. If it's per user, then yes - definitely double check if the user is checking his own page.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you cannot set cookies when output has already been sent to the browser. A useful trick is to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). Basically, you begin your code with a call to `ob_start()` and end it with `ob_end_flush()`. Now you can set cookies (and any HTML header) wherever you want in your code.

Comment: Right.  That way the code wont print out until you flush or clean it